# Change default application font

Tags: qt, qtwidgets

I have a Qt application that parses some JSON files and outputs its contents. I want the output to be in a monospaced font and the simplest way to do that is changing the default font of the entire application to a monospace. How do I do that in Qt?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Simply use the [`setFont()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#setFont) method on the `QApplication` or `QWidget`:

```
QFont font("Courier New");
font.setStyleHint(QFont::Monospace);
QApplication::setFont(font);
```

Note the [`setStyleHint(QFont::Monospace)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfont.html#setStyleHint) line: it ensures that even if the specified font family is not present in the system, another suitable monospace font will be used.

---

Also, in my opinion it's better to set font for a certain widget, **not** the whole application: this gives you a more structured code for your UI in case of its expansion. However, this is still a matter of a design, of course.

Comment: For some strange reason, even with the latest QT; you need to remove the alias to get it working.

Answer (score 8):

The only way I have figured out to change the font for a whole application in Qt is with stylesheets. For PyQt in the application's init class you can call `self.setStyleSheet('QWidget {font: "Roboto Mono"}')`. Due to the cascading nature of stylesheets this will set the font of all widgets to Roboto Mono.

Just setting `QApplication.setFont(font)` has not always worked for me. Sometimes deeply nested child widgets do not seem to respect the font, such as headers in QTreeView.